# SMTP Codeigniter email error '354 End data with .'

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp

I'm having trouble getting the Codeigniter email library working on a new server.

This code has previously worked before but has recently stopped working and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Essentially, here is the code:

```
 $this->email->from('example@example.com', 'Intranet');
 $this->email->to($c['email']);//This is def a valid email

 //$name is being obtained from elsewhere

 $this->email->subject('Time manager reminder');
 $this->email->message("
   {$name[0]},
   <br/><br/>You haven’t completed your time for today. Please don’t forget to do so<br/><br/>
   Intranet
  ");

 $this->email->send();
```

And the email.php config password

```
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['priority'] = 1;
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";

$config['smtp_host'] = "my server..";
$config['smtp_user'] = "u/n";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "p/w";

$config['smtp_timeout'] = 1;
$config['validate'] = true;
```

The error I receive from `$this->email->print_debugger();`          is as follows:

```
data: 354 End data with .

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this   method.
```

You can view the full error on pastebin here http://pastebin.com/y9UeaEGY

I've crossed out the emails in all places, but I can assure you they are valid and used email addresses.

I'd appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks

Comment: 354 can mean you've got some weird content in your message.
It looks like the apostrophes you are using in your message may not be standard apostrophes... what happens when you remove your apostrophes?

Comment: Hi. I've tried changing 'You haven’t' to 'You have not' and it's still producing the same error.

Comment: You have the same apostrophe in `don't`... did you change both?

Comment: Oops. Yeah, removed that too. Still no luck.

Comment: Can you attempt to send using sendmail (not smtp), or is that not configured on your server?  Also, your SMTP timeout is set to 1 second - could that be truncating your message?  What if you update the timeout to like, 30 seconds for a test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the reason. Apparently, in the config, you need to set

```
$config['crlf']     = "\r\n";
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
```

manually in the email.php file. Codeigniter doesn't seem to do it by default. Odd :)

Comment: On Expression Engine it's $config['email_crlf']     = "\r\n"; and $config['email_newline']  = "\r\n";